# Pattern matching issue in sql

Tags: sql

I've got certain DML statements and want to check if these statements correspond to table names that I have in my database.

For example suppose I have a database that contains the following tables:

1) Emp

2) Employee

3) Order

4) Orders

And then there's a **DML statement**: `insert into Emp values(<some values>)`

I want to check if this statement is an insert statement for one of my tables, and also want to discern the table that it is being fired on. (I'll be retrieving table names from sys.tables, in case you're wondering)

The pattern that I have been able to come up with (for instance, for an insert statement into Emp table) is:

`<statement> LIKE 'INSERT%[[<space><tab>'+char(13)+char(10)+']Emp[<space><tab>'+char(13)+char(10)+']]%'`

This is to take into account all the ways that a table's name might appear in an SQL statement, i.e. it will either have spaces around it, or maybe a carriage return etc. A table's name could also be surrounded by `[]`. Ergo I have made an effort to check that as well.

However, the above pattern is not working correctly. But if I were to change the pattern  to

`<statement> LIKE 'INSERT%[[<space><tab>'+char(13)+char(10)+']Emp[<space><tab>'+char(13)+char(10)+']%'` i.e. get rid of one `]`

it works correctly.

How do I find a way around this?

This is more like, how to check for `]` inside `[]` i.e. something like `[abc]]`.
So this should `match a or b or c or ]`

Comment: This seems to me a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: This can get very complicated. `INSERT INTO emp`, `insert INTO dbo.emp`, `INSERT /*new employee*/ INTO emp`, but not `update emp /*insert into emp failed, means we must update*/ set ...`, etc.